# query not working with desired output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write the query to display posterTitle and corrosponding AVERAGE SCORES seprated by comma. but i am not getting it.

```
SELECT submission.postertTtle, GROUP_CONCAT(judge_review.avgPoints) as 
avgPoints FROM submission,sub_judge,judge_review WHERE 
submission.submissionID=sub_judge.sub_id and 
sub_judge.judge_id=judge_review.j_ID GROUP by submission.postertTtle

 Desired Output:


posterTitle | avgpoints
Conference  | 5,3,1
new poster  |   1.5,2
```

[image: judge_review table.]

[image: sub_judge table]

[image: submission table]

Comment: Please post the data as text in a code block instead of using images, it helps a lot when trying to answer.

Comment: can you pls ans it with this format only.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select submission.postertTtle, GROUP_CONCAT(judge_review.avgPoints) as avgPoints 
 FROM submission 
 INNER join judge_review ON submission.submissionID=judge_review.sub_ID 
 GROUP by submission.postertTtle
```

Comment: This one is final answer which i want.